# Image not loaded for page with og tags when first time pasting to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have page https://pixit.im/AAC
It contains video and has correct og tags. OG Debugger says everything is fine with it and shows image from og:image there.

However, when I first time pasting this link to facebook, I do not see image on preview, only text form og:title and og:description.

If I open url in FB OG debugger, or paste it later, or post record with this link, the image appears.

But, the fact is, that every time I first time paste some link from my resource(https://pixit.im/A**) to FB share dialog, it does not load image for preview. The question is - why?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer is to also set `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`.

See also:
[Facebook Open Graph No Image First Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913369/facebook-open-graph-no-image-first-time/27913458#27913458)

(In my own testing, I found that setting `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` is sufficient. Setting `og:image:type` is unnecessary.)