# Facebook Open Graph No Image First Time

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to configure a share/send button with a link. I've properly configured the open graph image tags on a page, but when opening the share/send dialog for the first time, the image doesn't show. Without refreshing the page, opening the share/send dialog for the second time, the image will show. The URL of the page and the images are all in HTTP (instead of HTTPS).

I can't simply use the URL-Linting tool as the page will have a unique URL. The website is about sending virtual flowers to people and so the page to be shared is freshly generated.

Would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share on Facebook - Thumbnail not showing for the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226392/share-on-facebook-thumbnail-not-showing-for-the-first-time)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found the problem. Somehow this problem happens if you don't set your open graph tags properly.

Incorrect:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://asdfg.com/<%= videoId %>/image" />
```

Correct:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://asdfg.com/<%= videoId %>/image" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://asdfg.com/<%= videoId %>/image" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="640" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="442" />
```

Comment: Had the same issue, setting the type, width and height fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: +1, thanks! By the way, in my own testing, I found that setting width and height is sufficient; setting type is unnecessary.

Comment: Wow... setting width and height solved the ussue. Tnx.

Comment: Please note, that your original tag WAS set properly, as facebook defines width and height as OPTIONAL. So it still should be regarded as a facebook bug.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Not sure if anything has changed on the Facebook end.

Comment: Worked for me as of 8/30/2015. It's annoying working with Facebook related stuff because answers are irrelevant weeks later.

Comment: First testing the link with the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) also works, but that is annoying and this answer is better.

Comment: Worked for me on 7/13/16 - boy it sure would be nice if Facebook would document this :)

Comment: This is not working for me. I've added every single tag listed and it still doesn't pick it up.

Comment: 2017-02-06 - did not work for me, added all the tags, still no image load on first share.

Comment: I've tried every single answer here, none of them make the image load on the first share attempt.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

This solution with iframe **is not working anymore**! Worked since yesterday 06 February 2017.
Facebook just set **X-Frame-Options** as **DENY** so you cannot load the sharer url in an iFrame.

---

I added og:image:width and og:image:height, checked all my property tags and the problem was still there.

I found a workaround for this facebook bug that worked: I added an hidden iFrame with the sharer link in the page footer; in this way the facebook crawler check the page once is loaded.

```
<iframe style="width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" src="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: This hack totally works, after adding the og:image:width/height nothing would work but this. One note is to add border:0 and position:absolute or some browsers will show a space for the iframe. Final code would be: `<iframe style="width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; position:absolute;" src="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com"></iframe>` Of course don't forget to replace `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com` with the url of the page you are trying to share.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Note that this hack can load your site... but this is the only way I found for this (facebook) bug. I don't suggest to use this solution in blogs. I suggest you to use it when you have a page result always different (eg: www.nametest.com or www.daysoldage.com )

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone.

I found that Facebook did not like the square image I used (1000px x 1000px),
so I cropped it to 660px x 315x and Facebook accepted it.

Setting og: width and height did not help and it was literally about the image dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible answer that worked for me - make sure you have the og:image meta tag set before all the other tags, otherwise it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the image link correctly in the `og:image` property. If you still not get the thumbnail, add image `height` and `width` like this:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="450" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="298" />
```

Comment: this is the working solution! more about this i found here: https://medium.com/web-design-web-developer-magazine/facebook-share-dialog-box-not-showing-image-the-first-time-you-share-a-story-ed19d0f3ad36

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it will help someone.
No idea why, but after removing this from my 'head' block

```
<link rel="image_src" href="{MY_IMAGE_URI_HERE}" />
```

The problem has been solved.

---

Here's my meta tags

```
...
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{APP_ID}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://{IMAGE_THUMB_URI}" /> 
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://{IMAGE_THUMB_URI}" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="450" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="236" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{PAGE_URI}"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="{PAGE_TITLE}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{PAGE_DESC.}"/>
...
```

I'm using 'https' in both meta tags (**og:image** & **og:image:secure_url**), because the website is using ssl.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having problems, you may also need to add the **`MIME type`** property, like this:

`<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">`

**NOTE:** that's `image/jpeg` not `image/jpg` — (you gotta have the `e` in there)

FB crawler accepts `image/gif`, `image/jpeg`, `image/png`