# Can we refresh a page by using url parameters?

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, socialshare

In my rails application i am using social-share-button gem to share an Url on Facebook. While sharing for the very first time , Facebook is not fetching the image and if i refresh again it's fetching the image. Is there any way to refresh the Facebook from Url parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that the social-share-button gem correctly defines the OpenGraph meta tags, like `<meta property="og:....>` and/or that you set them manually.

An exact answer can be [found in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913369/facebook-open-graph-no-image-first-time), which does not seem related to the gem you're using.